# Probability (conditional): calculating the probability of an event happening twice

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Need to calculate P(aa). 
these two following approaches are obviously not the same, and the second one is wrong but I do not understand why:

1:
P(aa) = P(aa|b)P(b)+P(aa|!b)P(!b) = P(a|b)P(a|b)P(b)+P(a|!b)P(a|!b)P(!b)

2:
P(aa) = P(a)P(a) = (P(a|b)P(b)+P(a|!b)P(!b))^2

what's wrong with the second approach?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You need to provide more context.  For example $P(aa)$ seems to represent something happening twice in which case each $a$ a different event, not the same event, and these two events my be linked in some unexplained way.  Both your calculations seem to assume some conditional independence (given $b$ or $!b$) or unconditional independence between the two $a$ events in some unexplained way.  It really is not possible to comment meaningfully without more explanation of the situation

Comment: b is having disease, a is testing positive for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you write $P(aa)$ you mean the probability that $X_1=a$ and $X_2=a$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables. Similarly, I'm assuming that $b$ is the outcome of another random variable $Y$.

> If this interpretation is correct, then without any more information I
> would have to say that both equations could be wrong.

### Regarding your first equation:

It is true that $$P(X_1=a, X_2=a) =\\ P(X_1=a, X_2=a |Y=b)P(Y=b) + P(X_1=a, X_2=a | Y\neq b)P(Y\neq b),$$

(this is what you have in the first part of point 1 which follows from the law of total probability). However, the second part of point 1 is *not necessarily correct*, unless you are assuming that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are **conditionally independent**.

### Regarding your second equation:

In general *you can't assume* that $P(X_1=a, X_2=a) = P(X_1=a)P(X_2=a)$, unless you are assuming that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are **independent** random variables.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write the answer. What will be the situation assuming 'b' is "having a disease" and 'a' is "testing positive fir said disease"?

Comment: I think I got it... what you say is that because testing positive once increase the chance that the patient has the disease, testing positive for a second time has a higher probability... hence bo

Comment: hence the two variables are not independent... (sorry, my cat prematurely clicked 'post' before)

Comment: @pHbits I think I understand your question better now :) Basically $P(aa)$ is the probability of testing positive *twice*. In this case, $X_1$ is the variable "result of first test" and $X_2$ is the variable "result of the second test". So, $P(aa) = P(X_1=\text{positive}, X_2=\text{positive}) = P(X_1=\text{positive}|X_2=\text{positive})P(X_2=\text{positive})$. As you correctly surmised in your comment, $P(X_1=\text{positive}|X_2=\text{positive})\neq P(X_1=\text{positive})$ so the second equation is wrong.